# what is the equivalent of varbinary(10) in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, bit-fields

I'm trying to define a `bit` field of 10 bytes. In SQL Server I'd use `varbinary(10)`. I know that `bytea` replaces `varbinary (MAX)` for images, but didn't find any documentation on limiting the number of bits in it.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 11):

you want to look at bit(n), not bytea

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html